# Панель для ввода IP-адреса

Tags: android, android-edittext, клавиатура

Хочу сделать панель-клавиатуру для поля ввода IP-адреса. На клавиатуре должны присутствовать точка и двоеточие. Варианта стандартной клавиатуры я не нашел. Пытался поменять `imeActionLabel` к `numberDecimal`, но системная клавиатура отказывается выставлять указанную строку.

В итоге я пришел к тому, чтобы написать панель, которая бы выдвигалась снизу, словно это клавиатура. Однако моего знания Android'а недостаточно для самостоятельного решения этой задачи.

Буду очень признателен примерам реализации таких панелей, а так же подсказкам. Прежде всего реализации появления панели на экране - содержимое панели я худо-бедно сам настрою.

Comment: Можно создать свою клавиатуру (custom keyboard). Примеры создания вижу [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard) и [тут](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615). Это только первые ссылки по запросу в Google "android custom keyboard", так что стоит и остальные посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Ну если вам нужна выдвижная панель то это смотреть на BottomNavigationView. Свою клавиатуру пилить это не вариант, потому что ее пользователь должен будет по умолчанию поставить. А вообще лучше сделать маску на поле в которое нужно вводить IP адрес

Comment: Маска будет сделана, суть в другом: неудобно вводить ip-адрес, приходится переключаться на символы, переходить на цифры и т.д.

Comment: Если у вас маска будет, то зачем тогда двоеточия  самому писать. Пусть их маска и добавляет

Comment: видимо предполагается не полноценная клавиатура, а просто панель с цифрами и двоеточием, не вместо, а одновременно с основной клавиатурой, но готовая маска, куда вводить только цифры гораздо более предпочтительный вариант.

Comment: как вы собираетесь отслеживать, где должно быть 3 символа, а где 2 или 1? Клавиатура читать мысли не умеет, маска тоже. Нужен простой и очевидный вариант, клавиатура на которой только цифры, точка и двоеточие.

Comment: можно написать 0 впереди. И тогда везде три знака будет. А если это не устраивает, то пишите не кастомную клавиатуру а просто набор кнопок на bottomnavigationview

Answer (score 1):

Обрати внимание на эту библиотеку, легка в использовании и обеспечит необходимый функционал.
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4642